# Issue with Destroy Method in Controller - ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

When I try to delete an article from a wiki, it throw an error "can't find article with id..."

destroy method:

```
def destroy
    @article=Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    flash.notice="Article '#{@article.title}' was deleted"

    redirect_to article_path
end
```

show view (show.html.erb):

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
<p><%= @article.body %></p>
<%= link_to "<<Back to Articles List", articles_path %>
<%= link_to "Delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete this article?"} %>
```

Comment: inspect your params in the controller

Comment: also paste the params from `log` or by `inspecting params`

Comment: The error message is obvious already. ActiveRecord just throw an exception that it couldn't find any record that match your params[:id]. Check your params[:id] again, and make sure that you have that record in your database

Comment: this might be the issue of wrong url @SomethVictory. e.g host/articles/article/1. Beginners face this problem

Comment: I think the delete should be ok, and the url path should be /articles/:id. The problem should be on the instance variable @article, or probably there is no that record in the database, maybe he deleted it manually from the console

Comment: Is your browser passing the request as DELETE? pls paste the params.

Answer (score 1):

I just get the same problem as this. All you need to do is to change "redirect_to article_path" to "redirect_to articles_path". They are two different paths.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`When I try to delete an article from a wiki, it throw an error "can't find article with id..."`

The error message says it all. You are trying to delete an object that does not exist. It perhaps used to exist but it doesn't exist anymore.

example: let's say the error message says `"can't find article with id=5"`.

open your `rails console`, and search for article with id=5:

```
Article.find(5)
```

it will tell you it could not find the article:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Child with id=5
```

Your codes look good. it is just that you are trying delete something that does not exist.

back to the `console`, locate an existing article. try deleting that article and you'll notice your code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is going to be here:

> 1. Your db doesn't have the record you're trying to remove
> 2. You aren't passing the right `paramd[:id]`

Without seeing your params log, I can only reference your `link_to` method in order to gain ideas as to what happened. If you want a more informed response, you'll want to show us the `params` hash you receive to your method

--

**Fix**

Why not try calling the object directly (so `link_to` will be able to reference the path as organically as possible):

```
<%= link_to "Delete", @article, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete this article?"} %>
```

This is, of course, considering your `@article` record was compiled correctly etc

--

Another issue you'll have is you are calling `redirect_to article_path` *after* you've destroyed your record.

Surely you'll want to redirect to `articles_path` - the `index` of the articles (according to a resourceful system)?

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller code is correct... then also check for both Methods...

```
def index
    @article = Article.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # call index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @article }
    end
  end

def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Check in your View **article/index.html.erb** file

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Article Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th> 
  </tr>
<% @article.each do |article| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= article.title %></td>
    <td><%= article.body %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', article %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Article', new_article_path %>
</div>
```

Still if you are getting an error then 
add to your `destroy` method

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id]) rescue ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Dis you insert code at articles_controller.rb?

```
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
```